# i18next: как верно определять язык?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, next.js

Я использую i18next в своем проекте. При переключении языка я подставляю префикс языка в ссылку. Но если это язык по умолчанию - то упускаю префикс. Например:

```
/en/news
/news

/en/about
/about
```

После перезагрузки язык становится дефолтным, хотя в ссылке будет /en. Что бы это исправить, взял плагин [i18next-browser-languagedetector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-browser-languagedetector)

Там есть вариант определения path и это по сути то, что мне надо. Но так как у меня дефолтный язык выводится без префикса - появляется ошибка. Как ее обойти - не знаю.

Хотел так же написать свой детектор, но не могу получить ссылку. При попытке получить window.local, говорит, что

```
window is not defined
```

Может кто решал эту проблему и использует другой плагин - напишите, буду благодарен